# Check for words in input text from words collection

Tags: stanford-nlp, wordnet

I have collection of Noun Phrases say around 10,000 words. I want to check every new input text data for these NP collection and extract those sentences that contains any of these NP. I don't want to run loops for every word because it makes my code dead slow. I am using Java and Stanford CoreNLP.

Comment: Did you write any code yet, for the slow version you currently have? If you edit it into the question and show us what you got, someone may be able to improve on it and help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to do this is to use RegexNER to identify all examples of anything in your dictionary, and then check for non "O" NER tags in the sentence.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FindSentencesWithPhrase {

  public static boolean checkForNamedEntity(CoreMap sentence) {
    for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
      if (token.ner() != null && !token.ner().equals("O")) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,regexner");
    props.setProperty("regexner.mapping", "phrases.rules");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String exampleText = "This sentence contains the phrase \"ice cream\"." +
        "This sentence is not of interest.  This sentences contains pizza.";
    Annotation ann = new Annotation(exampleText);
    pipeline.annotate(ann);
    for (CoreMap sentence : ann.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      if (checkForNamedEntity(sentence)) {
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).
            stream().map(token -> token.word()).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The file "phrases.rules" should look like this:

```
ice cream       PHRASE_OF_INTEREST      MISC    1
pizza   PHRASE_OF_INTEREST      MISC    1
```

Comment: You can set the "regexner.ignorecase" to true or false depending on if you want to it to be case-sensitive or not.